# CKAN and API gateway

Tags: ckan

I am able to put CKAN api behind apigateway mainly to get rate limiting. However users can bypass the apigatway and call the CKAN api directly. Is there a way to prevent users from calling CKAN api directly?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Configure your webserver to put the API URLs behind some auth, and supply the auth to API Gateway so it (alone) can still access them.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Apache web server access control config to only allow connections from your api gateway infrastructure.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Require host address
Require ip ip.address_of_api_manager